# Finding a row with specific column value in jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

I am trying to get the data for a row by matching a column value. For example if we have the following data in the grid, I want to get the data of the row which has a `CombinedID = 2015-01-02-0222`.

```
[
    {"Name":"Test 1", "CombinedID":"2015-01-02-0111", "Description":"Testing"},

    {"Name":"Test 2", "CombinedID":"2015-01-02-0222", "Description":"Testing 2"},

    {"Name":"Test 2", "CombinedID":"2015-01-02-0333", "Description":"Testing 3"}
]
```

Cannot find a straight forward method in jqxGrid documentation.

Was looking for something like this (but cannot find any such method yet):

```
var rowData = $(grid).jqxGrid('getRowByColumnValue','CombinedID',"2015-01-02-0222");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a function myself to get the rows which matches the column value:

```
function getItemsByColumnValue(grid, field, value, selectField) {
    var rows = $(grid).jqxGrid('getboundrows');
    var output = [];
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        if(row[field] == value) {
            if(selectField) {
                //if selectField is specified, put only that field value to array
                output.push(row[selectField]);
            } else {
                output.push(row);
            }
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, I was looking into the best way to do this and your way works.  The only thing I'm trying to do now is retrieve the row index for these results so I can use them programmatically, any idea?

Comment: @TravisO the rowdata has fields called `boundindex` and `visibleindex`. You can get it by calling like this : `getItemsByColumnValue(grid, field, value,'boundindex');`